# Динамическое создание списков <Select> в JS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Господа, может кто помочь решить такую задачу: есть кнопка при нажатии на которую, каждый раз создается новый список "select" с одним и тем же именем, а элементы "option" получались из базы данных sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать такой вариант.

С помощью [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement) - создаем `select`,
и с помощью [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement) и [HTMLSelectElement.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) - создаем `option` из вашего списка и добавляем в `select`

```js
const body = document.body;
const listOptions = ["JS", "HTML", "CSS"];
const listSelects = [];

function createSelect() {
  const select = document.createElement("select");
  listSelects.push(select);
  select.id = `select_${listSelects.length}`;
  select.name = `selectName`;
  body.appendChild(select);

  for (let i = 0; i < listOptions.length; i++) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    // option.selected = ...;
    // option.disabled = ...;
    option.value = listOptions[i];
    option.text = listOptions[i];
    select.add(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="createSelect()">Создать select</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !