# Почему селекты перестают работать после клонирования?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

не открываются дропдауны (только в первом селекте)
а если убрать display none для второго итема - то он будет работать

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".social").select2({
    templateResult: formatState,
    templateSelection: formatState
  });


});

$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
  let elem = $('.item.copy').clone();
  elem.removeAttr('style');
  elem.removeClass('copy');
  $('.holder').append(elem);

})

let icons = {
  "Bumper": "https://i.imgur.com/50qd4Ub.png",
  "Roof": "https://i.imgur.com/lGOXYfV.png",
  "Door": "https://i.imgur.com/tSTGogW.png"
}

function formatState(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }

  var $state = $(
    `
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
       <div><img sytle="display: inline-block;" src="${icons[state.text]}" style="height: 30px;width: atuto;" /></div>
       <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
          ${state.text}
       </div>
    </div>
    `
  );
  return $state;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="holder">
  <div class="item">
    <p>1 item</p>
    <select class='social' name="states">
      <option value='bumper'>Bumper</option>
      <option value='twitter'>Roof</option>
      <option value='front_door'>Door</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="item copy" style='display: none'>
    <p>2 item</p>
    <select class='social ' name="states2">
      <option value='bumper'>Bumper</option>
      <option value='twitter'>Roof</option>
      <option value='front_door'>Door</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">
  склонировать элемент
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Почитайте...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244918/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-select-%D0%B2-js)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ, по-сути, содержится в вопросе. **Потому что вы динамически создаёте элемент.**

Инициализацию `select` вы делаете один раз после загрузки страницы, а при создании новых элементов `select` ничего не знает про них. Внутри себя он вещает слушателей только на конкретные идентификаторы, не используя делегирование. Поэтому после создания надо инициализировать селект на вновь созданном элементе.